# Set "select" field on a node programatically

Tags: nodes, 9

I am creating nodes programmatically on a specific content type. The content type has a "select field" that I am trying to set value with and cannot do it. Below is my code:

```
 $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
      'type'  => 'level3',
      'title' => $file_name,
      field_level2_title => [
        'value' => 'Assessment'
      ],
      field_level3_title => $file_name,
      field_level3_readmore => [
        'uri' => $file_uri,
        'title' => $file_name
      ],
    ));
```

The select field name is "field_level2_title and I am unable to assign this. Any help?

Comment: A select element is a widget, not a field type. What type of field is it? (Entity Reference, Text, etc)

Comment: It's an entity reference field.

Comment: Then you need to assign it the ref ID.

Comment: Ahh instead of value I should assign refid?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the comments above. the solution worked for me is as below:

field_level2_title => [
'target_id' => $ref_id_field
]